# I want to create table data from an array, and after 5 entries, create a new row. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, mapping

I have mapping function like this:

```
function MyFunction({rows}) {
        return(
        rows
        .map((info, index) => (
            <td key = {someNum}>
                <p>some info</p>
            </td>
        )));
}
```

and I want to add something that will create new rows after the index hits five:

```
function MyFunction({rows}) {
        return(
        rows
        .map((info, index) => (
            {(index+1 %5 === 0 || index === 0) && <tr>}
            <td key = {someNum}>
                <p>some info</p>
            </td>
            {(index+1 %5 === 0) && </tr>}
        )));
}
```

I can't get it to work, any ideas?

I've tried a lot of different syntax inside those curly brackets, but cant seem to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const chunk = (arr, size) => 
    Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(arr.length / size) }, (v, i) =>
       arr.slice(i * size, i * size + size)
);

const results = chunk(rows, 5);

return(
    results.map((array) => (
      <>
        <tr>
        {array.map((info) => (
           <td key = {someNum}>
              <p>some info</p>
           </td>
        ))}
        </tr>
      </>
   ))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a return statement

if you use arrow function like

```
const myFunction = () => doSomething(); // you don't need return
```

but if you use it like that

```
const myFunction = () => {
  return doSomething(); // you need return
}
```

In your case

```
   return(
        rows
        .map((info, index) => (
// here missing a return 
            {(index+1 %5 === 0 || index === 0) && <tr>}
            <td key = {someNum}> // 
                <p>some info</p>
            </td>
            {(index+1 %5 === 0) && </tr>}
        )));
```

Comment: hope it help you